# Migrate on premise SQL Server Database to AWS EC2 instances or AWS RDS using Data Migration Service?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-migration

I want to migrate my SQL Server Databases to AWS EC2 instances or AWS RDS using DMS Service of AWS?

How can I do that? What will be the architecture for the same? How to secure Databases in AWS?

What is the difference between both approaches? Can anyone provide architecture for both the approaches?

Answer (score 0):

We're in the middle of moving our on-prem SQL Servers to AWS EC2 right now. For us, we're adding replicas to existing Availability Groups. When the time comes, we'll fail over the AG and tada! we'll be in AWS. But even if we didn't have AGs, I'd *still* do this with backup/restore over DMS. From the little bit that I looked at DMS, you need either CDC or a rowversion column on every table you want DMS to work with. Which seemed like a lot to me.

In case you're not acquainted with moving a database with backup/restore, here's the bones of it.

1. Copy a full backup to the target system
2. Restore that backup, being sure to specify `with norecovery` to allow it to accept more backups
3. Copy/restore a differential backup, again specifying `with norecovery`
4. Copy/restore transaction log backups. You'll keep doing this on a periodic basis until you're ready to do your cut over.
5. When you're finally ready to turn off the source database, take a log backup of the source, specifying `with norecovery`. This will create what is called a tail of the log backup and will stop anything from being able to write to the source database. Copy/restore that last log backup over and you're migrated.